# Acrobat - Optimised PDF - Unembed fonts not working

Tags: adobe-indesign, fonts, pdf, adobe-acrobat, embed

I'm using Acrobat DC (version 2019.010.20098 - auto updated by Creative Cloud).

I need to unembed the fonts from a PDF file that I exported from InDesign. I do this via File > Save As Other > Optimised PDF...

This has worked for me many times in the past years. But it doesn't seem to be working at all now. I'm doing it correctly (move fonts from left pane to right pane to unembed them), but it literally seems to be doing nothing. Opening the optimised file shows that the fonts (subsets) are still embedded within.

It does work, however, with other random PDFs I've tested. It's as if exporting from InDesign produces a PDF from which the fonts cannot be unembedded.

Can anyone shed any light?

Comment: Does the PDF have security settings that are blocking edits?

Comment: Just a curiosity: why would you choose to unembed fonts?

Comment: @mrserge I have a very unique workflow in which I Create in InDesign -> Export to PDF -> Optimise PDF -> Print PDF to Microsoft XPS -> Extract XAML markup from XPS zip -> Include in a WPF app as a custom FixedDocument. If the fonts are embedded, then the XPS step produces an unusable file in which the text is encrypted and unselectable. The only way it works is to unembed the fonts (while making sure they are installed on my system anyway).

Comment: Why not extract XML directly from InDesign and work with that?

Comment: XAML, not XML...

Comment: Ok, got it. How about workflow InDesign -> (PDF without additional optimisation, just once created PDF Export Settings) -> Illustrator -> XAML Export? http://www.mikeswanson.com/xamlexport/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.

When I disabled the Transparency settings in the Optimise PDF workflow then the fonts were unembedded successfully.